# NSDocument intercept Save invoked from closing dirty document

Tags: cocoa, save, document, nsdocument

I am preparing version 3 of my app. When opening a version 2 file, it warns the user that if they save it, it will be converted to version 3 format.

When they choose Save from the File menu, it calls:

```
-(IBAction)saveDocument:(id)sender
```

in my document and warns them again before calling

```
[super saveDocument:sender];
```

The problem comes if the document is dirty and they close the window. The default system opens a sheet that has a "Save" button. If they click this button it seems to bypass my saveDocument method and calls immediately to my:

```
-(NSFileWrapper *)fileWrapperOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
```

How can I intercept this so that if they close a dirty document, I can make sure they know that saving will result in the file being converted into the new version format?

Comment: Override `- (void)canCloseDocumentWithDelegate:(id)delegate shouldCloseSelector:(SEL)shouldCloseSelector contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo`?